# Formating a phone number in c#

Tags: c#, phone-number

I'm trying to output a phone number in the format of (###) - (#######) in C# .
I did look up the String.Format() ,but never worked for my code.
Any ideas will be appreciated ,thanks.
I forgot to mention that I can not use arrays as I didn't reach this level yet.

Comment: How were you using String.Format()? Include code.

Comment: Yes, please add code.  Also this is a pretty google-able question...see http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ for example.

Comment: There is no special code , I mean I just read a string from the user wich is the phone number ,then I print it in the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Format works fine. You just need to use substring to break the original string into tokens.

```
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("({0})-{1}", phoneNum.SubString(0, 2), phoneNum.SubString(3, 9));
```

Comment: I did try this code but it gave me that it's out of range.

Comment: @sunflower that would happen if `phoneNum.Length` is less than 10. That function is expecting `phoneNum` to be a 10 digit string like 5036390644. `SubString` takes a starting and ending index and returns that component of the string you call it on.

Comment: It's atually working now ! Thank you very much :)))